# querying through wmi & win32.client objects with python

Tags: python, winapi

Could someone shed some lights upon querying through wmi and win32.client objects?

Anytime i try to query throught win32.client object i get this error:

> *Error: '' object has no attribute 'UserName'*

though, i know (wmic class "Win32_ComputerSystem", wmiexplorer etc.) the certain attribute belongs to the object i'm trying to query on:

```
import win32com.client
...
strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root/cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
for objItem in colItems:{
    print objItem.UserName    #Error: '' object has no attribute 'UserName'
}
...
```

And when i run query on wmi object - everything is just fine:

```
import wmi
...
c = wmi.WMI()
for objItem in c.query(colItems):{
    print objItem.UserName  # this works now
}
...
```

What is causing this "no attribute" error? Could this be my OS issue? Running winXP pro, version 2002, sp2. Or is this because of python 2.4 version i am working on?

Comment: Python doesn't use braces '{}' for code blocks.

Answer (score 3):

To find out about the "keys" and "values" in WMI query result, you can use "Properties_"

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch, GetObject import win32con
server = Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
c = server.ConnectServer("localhost", "root\\cimv2") 
p = c.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

for i in w.p[0].Properties_:
    print i.Name, " = ", i.Value
```

Comment: of course NameError: name 'w' is not defined and it's not clear the use of this import win32con

Answer (score 1):

try to access properties of colItems this way:

```
for objItem in colItems[o].Properties_:
    print objItem.Name, objItem.Value
```

in other circumstances you may prefer to use

```
repr(objItem.Value)
```

and

```
repr(objItem.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this?

```
for objItem in colItems:{
    print objItem.UserName    #Error: '' object has no attribute 'UserName'
}
```

What causes you to think that the resulting columns will be attributes of the resulting object?

Try this to debug the problem.

```
for objItem in colItems:{
    print dir(objItem)
}
```

What actual attributes does it have?  Perhaps the columns are identified by number?  Perhaps you should be doing `objItem[0]`?

---

**Edit**

**what caused the change of attributes in class "Win32_ComputerSystem"??**

Nothing.  Attributes don't change.  The class is not what you think it should be.

Here's another debugging aid.

```
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
print type(colItems)
print dir(colItems)
```

Comment: thanks for a reply.
it's clear i am missing something... I've looked up for a "Win32_ComputerSystem" class in wmiexplorer - it states this class has an attribute of "UserName". So how come resulting columns are NOT the attributes of resulting object???

Comment: print dir(objItem):['AssociatorsAsync_', 'Associators_', 'CLSID', 'Clone_', 'CompareTo_', 'DeleteAsync_', 'Delete_', 'ExecMethodAsync_', 'ExecMethod_', 'GetObjectText_', 'InstancesAsync_', 'Instances_', 'PutAsync_', 'Put_', 'ReferencesAsync_', 'References_', 'SpawnDerivedClass_', 'SpawnInstance_'..

Comment: what caused the change of attributes in class "Win32_ComputerSystem"??

Comment: How come class is different from the specified one in ExecQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, here is another piece of code (from http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/211/189/):

```
import win32com.client
strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Environment")
for objItem in colItems:{
    print "Caption: ", objItem.Caption
    print "Description: ", objItem.Description
    print "Install Date: ", objItem.InstallDate
    print "Name: ", objItem.Name
    print "Status: ", objItem.Status
    print "System Variable: ", objItem.SystemVariable
    print "User Name: ", objItem.UserName
    print "Variable Value: ", objItem.VariableValue
}
```

And again the same error is being displayed:

```
Caption: Error: '' object has no attribute 'Caption'
```

What is happening? How come class is different from the specified one in ExecQuery? I mean, if one says "Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem", how can it query different class than Win32_ComputerSystem?

By the way, I am running python 2.4 code through spyce 2.0.3 server.

p.s. I found that brackets {} is one way to get python code block interpreted right - otherwise "expected an indented block" error is thrown