Im trying to find a volume named "TOSHIBA" which is a flash drive in python. I want it so that I get the drive letter for a windows machine
I want something similar to this powershell line "$u=(Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | Where-Object {$_.Label -eq 'TOSHIBA'}).DriveLetter" but in python.
I haven't tried anything, but this powershell line works and i want something similar to it in python.

Could be a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685351/querying-through-wmi-win32-client-objects-with-python

Install pywin32 and the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) libraries to get access to the API.
import wmi

# Create a WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) object
f = wmi.WMI()

# Query Win32_Volume and filter by Label 'TOSHIBA'
volumes = f.Win32_Volume(Label="TOSHIBA")

# Iterate through the filtered volumes
for volume in volumes:
    # Get the DriveLetter attribute of the volume
    drive_letter = volume.DriveLetter
    print(f"Drive Letter: {drive_letter}")
    break

